# Does Java use JNI "out-of-the-box"?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

It is not conceptually clear to me as to when Java uses JNI. The literature <sup>1,2</sup> seems to suggest using JNI is optional - it is a useful feature for my own, existing native C applications, but it is good practice to avoid using it when possible:
Liang indicates "Remember that once an application uses the JNI, it risks losing two benefits [of portability and security]".

However, I was looking at Oracle's API implementation in the SDK, and I see `public static native void arraycopy` in `java/lang/System.java`. Questions:

1. Don't methods marked as such, in native, use JNI?
2. Doesn't Java make use JNI when making system calls?

System calls are required for any Java API implementation, so if I'm correct, it seems there is no avoiding interfacing with native code.

<sub>1: Horstmann, Core Java Volume 2

2. Liang, The Java™ Native Interface Programmer’s Guide and Specification</sub>

Comment: Java applications can be portable. Java implementations cannot. So an implementation doesn't lose portability by using JNI.

Comment: @TomBlodget You mean an *application* doesn't lose portability by using JNI? That would make sense - I'm not sure why the author made that statement; I'll have to go back and check.

Comment: I mean that an implementation doesn't lose portability by using JNI because it never had it. It's platform-specific regardless of the methods it uses to call operating service functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Don't methods marked as such, in native, use JNI?

Yes, that's what it means.

> 2. Doesn't Java make use JNI when making system calls?

Same question really. Only native methods can call system calls, so Java code can only call system calls via native methods.

Using JNI is optional *for applications.* It's essential for the JVM.

Answer (score 5):

You list two drawbacks of JNI - *portability* and *security*. Actually, there is another one, which is more important in everyday life: JNI calls bear a significant *performance cost*, because they affect the global JVM state and lock some JVM features, including GC.

As detailed in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861526/192373), JVM does rely on JNI. But this is not a complete answer.

Your JVM may support fast JNI methods (e.g. Android ART does). These methods are guaranteed to be fast and non-blocking, and they may be performed without state change, see e.g. [@FastNative](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/improvements#faster-native-methods). The Java SDK native methods use such improvements a lot, so they don't suffer the *performance* costs of conventional JNI.

These native methods do not rely on `LoadLibrary()` during run. This removes another significant performance cost of JNI - loading and 'binding' the native methods at runtime. The worst risk with runtime binding is that it happens at an arbitrary time, determined by the classloader, and may clash with some other urgent thing that your JVM or app must do at that time. Irrelevant for the system native methods.

Also, *portability* concerns are irrelevant: the Java runtime is carefully crafted for each supported platform, and in itself it is not 'portable', only the Java apps running on top of it are.

Finally, *security* risks of JNI are twofold: JNI is not limited by *private* declarations, and the native code can do dangerous things that compromise any class or app running in the same JVM. And, being loaded from a third-party library, JNI code may be hacked (e.g. it's enough to change OS environment to cause `System.loadLibrary()` load a fraudster's version of the lib). The system native methods are immune to such attacks.

In the nutshell, even though JVM does use JNI, this is not an excuse to indiscriminately use JNI for your own classes.